# Wrong column type in jpa many to many relationship

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, joincolumn

I have the following many-to-many relationship

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="response"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="id_response", referencedColumnName="id_response")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="id_request")
            }
        )
private List<Transaction> transactions;
```

I get the following exception :

```
Wrong column type in response for column id_response.  Found: varchar, expected: integer
```

Is it possible to add a parameter to @JoinColumn to explicitly tell it is a String value ?
Any other solution ?

Comment: Why would you tell something the type ? The PK field(s) of the entities DEFINE the types. You haven't shown them ...

Comment: Thanks you helped me find my mistake.
The wrong type was because of a field type in my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake : The wrong type was because of a field type in my database.